# UIView rearranging on rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout

I'm using storyboard for the project. 
I have a top menu with 3 buttons (`UIView` with 3 `UIButton`'s in it) with the same distance between them.

I would like to stretch this menu to maximum width on rotation and increase the distance between buttons.

I did the following:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:orientation];
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)){
        [self prepareLandscapeLayout];
    }
}

- (void) prepareLandscapeLayout {   
    [[self topMenu] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, IS_IPHONE_5 ? 568 : 480, 59)];
    [[self cameraButton] setCenter:CGPointMake(232, 26)];
    [[self settingsButton] setCenter:CGPointMake(288, 26)];
    [[self videoList] setCenter:CGPointMake(340, 26)];
}
```

The `prepareLandscapeLayout` function is called after rotation, but buttons remain in their original positions. I can also see how `topMenu` stretches after rotation (I've changed the background color).

Are there any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Setting the center of the button won't stretch it, it will just move it. Change the actual frame of the button like you are doing it with the top menu

Comment: @danypata I don't want to resize them, I just need to put them to new position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you DON'T want to use storyboard desig for rotation and constraints you should stop using "Autolayout"

See `Interface Builder Document` in any controller on storyboard's right pane.

Answer (score 0):

Center is relative to its original orientation and is calculated from frame (also relative to original orientation).

Instead, try changing the frames to be relative to the parent view's bounds (which update based on orientation).

Comment: if I change setCenter to setFrame nothing changes.

Comment: When changing the frame, use topMenu.bounds instead of topMenu.frame.

Answer (score 0):

If the topMenu's frames is changing then write like.

```
- (void) prepareLandscapeLayout 
{   
[[self topMenu] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, IS_IPHONE_5 ? 568 : 480, 59)];
[[self cameraButton] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,actualWidth,actualHeight)];
[[self settingsButton] setFrame:CGRectMake(topMenu.frame.size.width/3,0,actualWidth,actualHeight)];
[[self videoList] setFrame:CGRectMake((topMenu.frame.size.width/3)*2,0,actualWidth,actualHeight)];
}
```

Comment: Is the topMenu's frame changing in orientation?

Comment: well, if fact it rotates with phone, but stays sticked to current upper part of phone (it looks like url bar in safari landscape mode) and stretches to full width of phone.